# is it possible to use MVP pattern with Codesmith Ntier or PLINQO Template

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, mvp, codesmith

Currently we are working on ASP .net application and i would prefer to go ahead with MVP pattern (for UI) due to several advantage it provides,

But the con of going ahead with that approach is too much of hand coding which will eat up time.

I already identified that it is possible to generate DAL with any template or by using LINQ to SQL but the only issue is with generating interface which should be implemented by usercontrol (view) and some boilerplate code (for data binding)

Now the question is

1) Is it possible to use codesmith template to get the MVP pattern (To generate interface & properties at UI layer as well as data binding)

2) It is not advisable to go ahead with MVP pattern and use the simple approach provided by codesmith template generator or any other tool

Note : I have also considered to go ahead with ASP .Net MVC but due to lack of knowledge (learning requirement) and project time line we have to drop that idea.

EDIT : In terms of man month effort it is of around 35-40 man month's effort to develop this application

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Absolutely possible. The "how" depends quite a lot on what specifically you are doing and how well templates fit your patterns (or how well your needs can be distilled to code generation in general).

2) Impossible to say. Depends entirely on your needs.

You should really investigate [ADO.NET Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx) and [ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488545.aspx) Scaffolding frameworks. These are designed exactly to do the kind of generation you are asking for.

Comment: is it required to customize codesmith template or in general there is one available which we can use directly

Comment: As far as Dynamic data is concerned, i identified that much of the application are still not developed using dynamic data concept. so, i am not sure that what are the problems or issues we may face down the road in application development. Can you suggest some link so i feel more confident about dynamic data concept should be used for enterprise application

Comment: The links in my original answer should be sufficient to get started. There are tons of other sites (just google them) that cover it from just about every angle. The topic is far too large to fully discuss here on stackoverflow in sufficient detail. You'll need to do the research yourself and compare what it offers with your needs.

Comment: Codesmith is fantastic, but generating UIs is rarely that simple. Codesmith is one of the best tools if you want custom templates. If you want a more "out-of-the-box" generation I suggest Dynamic Data or a product like IronSpeed (http://www.ironspeed.com/). Just keep in mind that the more "generated" the solution, the harder it usually is to learn and customize for those unusual cases where generation isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but checkout the codesmith templates I just released.
http://community.codesmithtools.com/CodeSmith/m/templates/42499.aspx